# How to split Vue components out of a list-rendering?

Tags: vue.js

I like Vue and often use it to list options in a select box, (or sometimes divs in a flexbox). I'm wondering if there is a way to split a piece out of a for-loop during a Vue list rendering. Like this scenario:

I have 3 options:

- Option 1 - Blue
- Option 2 - Green
- Option 3 - Purple

I want to render these in a select box AND in a div below the select box, depending on which option is selected, a different div (with the color of the selected option in this example).

Is there a way to do this inside a Vue-list rendering?

Something like

```
<select>
    <option v-for="color in colors">{{color.color}}</option>
</select>

<div>{{color.color}}</div> <--This doesn't work, as it is out of the for loop
```

---

The only way I've been able to work around this is to make an object to hold all this stuff AND an "active element" like so:

```
class ColorHolder{
    constructor(){
        colors = []
        activeColor = {};
    }
}
```

Then, I put listeners on each color in the `<option>` boxes, setting the active color to whatever got clicked. Then I have a hidden  component, that is shown when they click a color in the option list.

It works, but it seems like there must be a better way, as I have to manually figure out which color was clicked and display the `<color-div>` of the correct type. I want to just use the Vue list-rendering to render a component outside of the list, keeping it linked to the component in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

piggy-backing off of @husam's answer

I would advise against using a `selectedColor` value. You should use index (arrays) or key (objects) so you don't end up duplicating data (in larger applications)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    colors: [
    {color: 'Red'},
    {color: 'Green'},
    {color: 'Blue'}
    ],
    colIndex: 0
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.6/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="colIndex">
    <option v-for="color, i in colors" :value="i">{{ color.color }}</option>
  </select>
  <div>{{ colors[colIndex].color }}</div>
</div>
```

You can also use a computed value

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    colors: [
    {color: 'Red'},
    {color: 'Green'},
    {color: 'Blue'}
    ],
    colIndex: null
  },
  computed: {
    selectedColor() {
      return this.colors[this.colIndex] || {};
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.6/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="colIndex">
    <option v-for="color, i in colors" :value="i">{{ color.color }}</option>
  </select>
  <div>{{ selectedColor.color }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, for select boxes at least. What if instead of `<option>` elements, the loop rendered `<divs>` instead? Is there a way to mimic the `v-model` on divs?

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify things by using `v-model` on the `select` element to pick the value of the selected option and insert it into your `div`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    colors: [
    {color: 'Red'},
    {color: 'Green'},
    {color: 'Blue'}
    ],
    selectedColor: 'Red'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.6/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedColor">
    <option v-for="color in colors" :value="color.color">{{ color.color }}</option>
  </select>
  <div :style="{background: selectedColor}">{{ selectedColor }}</div>
</div>
```